# Counting number of words between a predefined delimiter

Tags: r, string

What's the best way to count number of words between a predefined delimiter (in my case '/')?

Dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c('A DOG//1//', 
                        'CAT/WHITE///',
                        'A HORSE/BROWN & BLACK/2//',
                        'DOG////'))
```

Expected results are the following numbers..

2 (which are A DOG and 1)

2 (which are CAT and WHITE)

3 (A HORSE, BROWN & BLACK, 2)

1 (DOG)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strsplit` at one or more slash (`"/+"`) and count strings

```
lengths(strsplit(as.character(df$v1), "/+"))
#[1] 2 2 3 1
```

Comment: In `base R` another option is `lengths(gregexpr("/+", df$v1))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data doesn't have cases where a string (a) begins with "/" or (b) doesn't end with "/," then you can just count the number of times there's a chunk of slashes in order to get the number of chunks between slashes. So the following works for the data you've provided.

```
stringr::str_count(df$v1, "/+")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using stringr::str_split() and counting the number of nonblank strings...

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c('A DOG//1//', 
                        'CAT/WHITE///',
                        'A HORSE/BROWN & BLACK/2//',
                        'DOG////'))

sapply(stringr::str_split(df$v1, '/'), function(x) sum(x != ''))

[1] 2 2 3 1
```